# MVC Seed does not put data in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables with a relation between them.

Here are my models:

```
public  class Locations
{
  [Key]
  public int LocationID { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required!")]
  [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The name is too long. Max. 50 characters allowed!")]
  [Display(Name = "Location name:")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public int Position { get; set; }

  public virtual LocationType LocationType { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class LocationType
{
  [Key]
  public int LocationTypeID { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required!")]
  [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "The name is too long. Max. 25 characters allowed!")]
  [Display(Name = "Location type:")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public int Position { get; set; }

  public int HasChoicesOrInput { get; set; } 

  public virtual ICollection<Locations> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

In my configuration.cs file I have the following seed:

```
context.LocationType.AddOrUpdate(a => a.LocationTypeID,
  new LocationType
  {
    Name = "AAAAA",
    HasChoicesOrInput = 1,
    Position = 1,
    Locations = { new Locations { Name = "1111111", Position = 1 },
                    new Locations { Name = "2222222", Position = 2 }
                }
  });
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Locations] (
[LocationID]                  INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]                        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Position]                    INT           NOT NULL,
[LocationType_LocationTypeID] INT           NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Locations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LocationID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Locations_dbo.LocationTypes_LocationType_LocationTypeID] FOREIGN KEY ([LocationType_LocationTypeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[LocationTypes] ([LocationTypeID])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LocationTypes] (
[LocationTypeID]    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]              NVARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
[Position]          INT           NOT NULL,
[HasChoicesOrInput] INT           NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.LocationTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LocationTypeID] ASC)
);
```

When I do an Update-Database, I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

Why? The tables exist in the database, the relation too.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Locations` intializer

```
new LocationType
{
  Name = "AAAAA",
  HasChoicesOrInput = 1,
  Position = 1,
  Locations = { new Locations { Name = "1111111", Position = 1 },
                new Locations { Name = "2222222", Position = 2 }
            }
});
```

does not create a `Locations` collection. It calls the property getter to get the existing `Locations` collection and calls `Add` on it. Since you never assigned anything to that property, you get the `NullReferenceException`.

This syntax is described in C# language specification, section 7.6.10.2 Object initializers:

> A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the equals sign is an initialization of an embedded collection. Instead of assigning a new collection to the field or property, the elements given in the initializer are added to the collection referenced by the field or property.
>   You should create a new instance of a collection (for example a list or an array) and assign it to `Locations` property in the initializer:

```
new LocationType
{
  Name = "AAAAA",
  HasChoicesOrInput = 1,
  Position = 1,
  Locations = new List<Locations> 
  { 
      new Locations { Name = "1111111", Position = 1 },
      new Locations { Name = "2222222", Position = 2 }
  }
});
```